# Automatically spacing the tilde (~) symbol as a prefix number using the `siunitx` package

Tags: siunitx, tilde

I'm trying to work out if there is a way to get `siunitx` to natively handle the ~ symbol (`\sim`) in the same way that it can handle the < and > operators before a number, as I would like to be able to use ~ as short hand for approximately.  For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

% Values output the same, with spacing after the < and before the % symbol
\SI{< 10}{\percent} \\
\SI{<10}{\percent} \\

% When writing in math mode a space in placed after the ~ symbol, but not before the % symbol
$\sim10\%$ \\

\end{document}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like `\SI{~ 10}{\percent}` or `\SI{\tilde}{10}{\percent}`, where `{\tilde}` is a custom value defined using the `DeclareSIUnit\tilde{~}` command.  But I can't seem to find anything like this for prefix symbols in the documentation.  Has anyone else come across a solution to this?

Comment: What does `\SI{\sim 10}{\percent}` have that doesn't work?

Comment: I thought I'd tried that permutation already and it didn't work.  But you're absolutely right, I've just tried it now and it does indeed work.  D'oh!  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `\SI{\sim 10}{\percent}` should be OK; maybe you want `\approx`, instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\SI{< 10}{\percent}   

\SI{<10}{\percent}   

\SI{\sim 10}{\percent}

\SI{\approx 10}{\percent}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I haven't seen an interface for new "prefixes" either, thus the following example patches internals of `siunitx`. Also I had trouble using `~` as prefix, probably because of rescans, where the catcode of `~` is set to 9, that ignores the characters. Therefore the example uses `\~` instead. `<>` is used a symbol for `\approx`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\exp_args:NNo \cs_set:Nn \__siunitx_number_in_sign_replace:N
 {
  \__siunitx_number_in_sign_replace:N { #1 }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn #1 { \~ } { \sim }
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn #1 { <> } { \approx }
 }
\tl_put_right:Nn \l__siunitx_input_protect_tl    { \~ }
\tl_put_right:Nn \l__siunitx_input_comparator_tl { \~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
  \noindent
  \SI{<10}{\percent}\\
  \SI{\~10}{\percent}\\
  \SI{<>10}{\percent}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Sorry, but your expl3 coding was terrible. `;-)` Isn't the fixed version better? With `\exp_args:NNo` we jump over two tokens and expand the first token after the `{`. I don't think Joseph will be happy to see this. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the improved LaTeX3 code :-) It is a pity, that at least some of the modules of LaTeX3 are not available for iniTeX or plain TeX, thus I cannot use it for many of my packages. Here, I first tried `etoolbox`, but `\apptocmd` cannot handle different catcodes for the same character (`-`) inside the definition.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek We discussed making the code work without relying on LaTeX (doable, if a little tricky). Please raise on LaTeX-L with a solid use case (Will and I were keen, Frank less so). Plain and IniTeX are easy: ConTeXt slightly more 'fun'.

Comment: Note that `~` is defined as having a particular meaning for `siunitx`, inherited from `SIstyle`, hence it can't really be supported in general input.

Comment: Another note: patching _internal_ `expl3` functions is specially _not supported_. This can and may well break at some point!